# Error in lines.etm(x[[i]], tr.choice = tr.choice[j], col = col[j + (i - : Argument 'tr.choice' and possible transitions must match

Tags: r, date, cumulative-frequency

When trying to plot cif data in R :

`plot(cif.kweet)` this error pops up:
    `"Error in lines.etm(x[[i]], tr.choice = tr.choice[j], col = col[j + (i -  : 
  Argument 'tr.choice' and possible transitions must match"`, what does this mean, how to solve it?

Additional information:

`cif.kweet <-etmCIF(Surv(entry, exit, cause !=0) ~ group, data, etype=data$cause, failcode=3)`

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.